# Can I use Ubuntu's crash kernel package with a manually installed kernel? [16.04]

Tags: 16.04, kernel, crash

Will the "linux-crashdump" package work with a manually installed kernel? I installed a kernel from linux-stable git. This package doesn't seem to work with this kernel according the the directions for this package at https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/kernel-crash-dump.html

edit:

Did you compile the kernel yourself? Yes

Does the kernel use the Ubuntu kernel configuration file? Yes, I copied it with the command:

```
cp /boot/config-`uname -r`* .config
```

Does the kernel configuration file have this: CONFIG_CRASH_DUMP=y? Yes, the .config file contains the line:

```
CONFIG_CRASH_DUMP=y
```

Comment: Did you compile the kernel yourself? Does the kernel use the Ubuntu kernel configuration file? Does the kernel configuration file have this: `CONFIG_CRASH_DUMP=y`?

Comment: @DougSmythies - Thanks, I responded to your questions with an edit.

Comment: Then I think it might work, but am not sure (which is why this is a comment and not and answer).